# Differences between groups and rings when understood as categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

A group can be understood as a category with a single object $*$ whose hom-set $\text{hom}(*,*)$ forms a group with composition as the group multiplication.

A ring can be understood as a category that is preadditive with a single object $*$. Preadditive means that for a category $C$, $\text{hom}_C(A,B)$ forms an abelian group that is distributive with respect to composition of arrows.

The group structure appears in different ways in these two categories. It seems weird to me that the group multiplication is the composition of arrows for groups as categories but for rings it is some binary map of arrows in the same hom-set. Why is this the 'best' way to understand these structures *as categories*? Is there some way to understand a ring as a category where composition of arrows forms a group (like the categorical sense of a group)?

Comment: You seem to expect category theory to provide a "best" way to understand the definition of an algebraic structure. Category theory is a very useful organising principle, but it isn't a panacea or a required dogma.

Comment: To Rob's comment, you can see that you're never going to realize a nonassociative operation in the same way as here, for groups and rings.

Comment: @RobArthan You make a good point. What I meant was "the best way to understand these structures as categories." I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of comparing groups and rings, one needs to compare *monoids* and rings:

- An one-object category is the same as a monoid.
- An one-object preadditive category is the same as a ring.

We see from this that the multiplication in a monoid needs to be compared to the multiplication in a ring.
The addition in rings has no corresponding structure in monoids.

Every ring has an underlying additive group, and some monoids happen to be groups. But that doesn’t matter for the above observation:
the multiplication in a group is a special case of the multiplication in a monoid, and therefore needs to be compared to the multiplication in a ring (and not the addition).
The addition in rings has no corresponding structure in groups.

Answer (score 7):

I think the basic way to understand a ring as a category is as **a monoid in the category of abelian groups**.

On one hand this says it is one abelian group $A$ and abelian group homomorphisms $Hom(A,A)$. But if you look at what it says when you identify the elements of $Hom(A,A)$ as "elements of the ring," it just says everything about distributivity of multiplication over addition.  The category axioms provide for the associativity of multiplication in the ring monoid.

A group is a **monoid in the category of sets** with the extra property that its arrows are isomorphisms.

So both are realized as monoid over different categories, and the group specializes by having extra requirements on its arrows.  The closest analogue for a ring is a division ring, of course, where all its nonzero arrows are isomorphisms.

### *Added*

Here are the details [for what a monoid in a category is.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory)). It is more involved than I remembered but it is worth working through as it provides a convenient viewpoint for many objects including rings, algebras, graded algebras, topological monoids etc.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not quite sure what you mean by "a monoid in the category of abelian groups." Is there a different or more precise way to put it? My understanding is that $Hom(A,A)$ forms an abelian group under addition of homomorphisms. Let $f,g,h \in Hom(A,A)$. How can I see $(f+g)\circ h = (f\circ h) + (g\circ h)$?

Comment: @rschwieb: Surely you don’t really mean “a monoid in $\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}\C$ is a one-object subcategory of $\C$”? That would make your answer’s main claim false!  “A monoid in a category $\C$” usually assumes (in my experience) that $\C$ is a *monoidal* category — then a monoid is a 1-object $\C$-enriched category; explicitly, an object $A$ with maps $A \odot A \to A$, $\mathbb{I} \to A$ satisfying associativity/unit laws. Under this sense, it’s true that a ring is a monoid in $\mathrm{AbGp}$, in the monoidal structure with $\otimes$ (not $\times$).

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine My impression as a cat. th. beginner is that it is perfectly fine to talk about monoids as categories without thinking of monoidal categories. (Mac Lane and Leinster do this in their books.) By the definition of a category, a single object category has an identity arrow and closure under composition of arrows that is associative; the monoid structure is evident. But perhaps Peter's explanation is the more useful mode in which monoidal structures often appear in practice?

Comment: @fred I do now remember the diagram definition of monoidal category he's referring to, and how the arrows basically encode all the distributivity. It may be more likely that over time I confounded that with simply "a one object subcategory" which is temptingly simple.  Maybe once I get my hands on a counterexample I will know one way or the other.  Thankfully my potential error is still only confined to the comments.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine You're right of course. I retract my comment, and revise to add a link to a complete discussion.

Comment: @fred The addition points to a complete discussion of what a monoid in a category is. Peter's right that we need at least what is known as a monoidal category.  It looks a little daunting but I assure you it is not as hard as it looks.  It is really just a rephrasing of the axioms to be in terms of arrows rather than elements.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know if this quite answers your question, but the point you focus on as your dissatisfaction seems to me to be a misunderstanding:

> It seems weird to me that the group multiplication is the composition of arrows for groups as categories but for rings it is some binary map of arrows in the same hom-set.

Viewing a ring as a one-object pre-additive (i.e. $\newcommand{\AbGp}{\mathrm{AbGp}}\AbGp$-enriched) category, **its multiplication is *precisely* composition of arrows**, *exactly* like in groups-viewed-as-one-object categories.  The point is that in single-object categories (plain or enriched), composition is exactly “some binary map of arrows in the same hom-set”, $\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}\C(*,*) \otimes \C(*,*) \to \C(*,*)$.

So I’d say the picture you set out is indeed a very good way to look at them:

- monoids (so in particular, groups) are 1-object categories;
- rings are 1-object categories enriched in $(\AbGp,\otimes)$ (aka monoids in $(\AbGp,\otimes)$);
- the forgetful functor $(\AbGp,\otimes) \to (\mathrm{Set},\times)$ is [lax monoidal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor); so it sends monoids in $(\AbGp,\otimes)$ to monoids in $(\mathrm{Set},\times)$, sending a ring to its underlying multiplicative monoid.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! To make sure I'm understanding properly, could you clarify two lingering concerns of mine? (1) Composition plays the role of multiplication for both rings and groups as 1-object categories but for rings each arrow need not have an inverse under composition while arrows forming a group do need an inverse. Do I have this correct? (I just want to make sure I'm interpreting your use of "exactly" properly.)

Comment: (2) My other concern is the ring distributivity. In Mac Lane's CWM (p.28 ed.2) I read that a preadditive category is defined s.t. $\mathcal{C}(a,b)$ is an additive abelian group for which composition is bilinear. I.e. for $f,f':a\rightarrow b$ and $g,g':b\rightarrow c$, $(g + g') \circ (f + f') = g\circ f + g\circ f' + g' \circ f + g' \circ f'$. The ring distributivity are therefore baked into the definition of a preadditive category, correct?

Comment: @fred (1) General 1-object categories are *monoids* — they don’t automatically have inverses — so rings and monoids are both instances of “1-object enriched categories”, or equivalently “monoids in a monoidal category”; then groups are a subclass of ordinary monoids.  (2) Yes: If you define preadditive cats with “composition is bilinear” as in CWM, distributivity comes precisely from that bilinearity.  If you define them as “$(\mathrm{AbGp},\otimes)$-enriched cats”, it comes from the fact that maps out of a tensor product correspond to bilinear maps.